# Problem set with separate hints and answers in latex

Tags: write-file

I'm making a problem set for a math course in latex. Each problem has a hint and an answer, both should be found at the very end of the document. But for easy editing I want to be able to type problems/hints/answers in the same place in the source file, I want to be able to write something like

```
\problem{problem text}{hint text}{answer text}
```

I have a setup like this that is somewhat working - it writes everything in the hints/answers parameters into separate files and then it inputs those file at the end:

```
\documentclass{article}

% Counters for problems and chapters
\newcounter{problem}
\setcounter{problem}{0}
\newcounter{chap}
\setcounter{chap}{1}


% Open files for hints and answers
\newwrite\hintsfile
\immediate\openout\hintsfile=hints.tex
\newwrite\ansfile
\immediate\openout\ansfile=answers.tex

% Custom problem command
\newcommand{\problem}[3]{%
    \addtocounter{problem}{1}%
    \noindent\llap{\textbf{\thechap.\theproblem.} }#1 \\ \vspace{1mm}
    
    
    % Write to hint file
    \immediate\write\hintsfile{\string\noindent\string\llap{\string\textbf{\thechap.\theproblem.}}}    
    \immediate\write\hintsfile{#2 \par}
        
    % Write to answer file
    \immediate\write\ansfile{\string\noindent\string\llap{\string\textbf{\thechap.\theproblem.}}}    
    \immediate\write\ansfile{#3 \par}   
}


\begin{document}
\section{Problems}
\problem{Problem 1 Text}{Hint 1 Text}{Answer 1 Text}
Text between problems\\
\problem{Problem 2 Text}{Hint 2 Text}{Answer 2 Text}
\problem{Problem 3 Text}{Hint 3 Text}{Answer 3 Text}

\immediate\closeout\hintsfile
\immediate\closeout\ansfile

\section{Hints}
\input{hints}

\section{Answers}
\input{answers}

\end{document}
```

The current problem is that I want to be able to use the \enumerate environment inside the problems/hints/answers, but it currently gives me an error (probably due to some parsing error when I'm trying to pass a whole math problem as a parameter).

What is the best way to do this?